# div display problems

Tags: jquery

This problem looks simple, so *mea culpa* in advance if it's poor etiquette to ask it.

I have some divs inside a tab panel div which is set to display.

```
<div id="fragment-5a" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="display: block;">
    <div id="mainpic">
    <img align="middle" alt="somewhere" 
    src="http://localhost/gopag3/projects/somest.jpg"></div> 
<div id="altpic"><img src="#"></div> 
<div id="mainpicblurb">texttexttext</div></div>
```

One div '**mainpic**' holds an img. The second '**mainpicblurb**' holds text and links inside a sub-div '**piclinks**'. Div '**altpic**' is empty and hidden (display:none) but otherwise an exact copy of 'mainpic'.

I am trying to write a script which does the following:

1. hides 'mainpic'
2. grabs href (img src) and adds it as img src to 'altpic'
3. shows 'altpic'

Here's what I have done.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#piclinks div a').click(function() {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#mainpic').hide();
        $('#altpic img').replaceWith('<img align="middle" src="' + link + '">');
        $('#altpic').show();
    return false;
    }); 
});
```

This does not work overall. The href is successfully grabbed. The img src is successfully dumped into 'altpic' and 'return false' works ok, but neither 'mainpic' or 'altpic' have the right display attribute.

It may be that the tabs CSS is overriding whatever I do, although looking at it in Firebug I can't see how.

It's perfectly possible the above is a long string of howlers. My gut instinct is that the selection process is wrong. I need to traverse the DOM from #piclinks div a back up the tree to gather in #mainpic and #altpic, using parent() and siblings(), possibly.

Anyway, suggestions/understanding criticism welcome.

Tom

Comment: the link points to an `img`? What's the path?
Why don't you try just changing the `attr` of the `img` instead of creating a new one? jQuery creates CSS inline so it can't be overriden by a CSS rule as far as I know...

Comment: The code you posted is perfectly fine. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kxk/). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thx S0pra - the fiddle is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

CSS hiding for a given id can be the issue. Try to add a class is-hidden for altpic:

```
<div id="fragment-5a" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="display: block;">
    <div id="mainpic">
    <img align="middle" alt="somewhere" 
    src="http://localhost/gopag3/projects/somest.jpg"></div> 
<div id="altpic" class="is-hidden"><img src="#"></div> 
<div id="mainpicblurb">texttexttext</div></div>
```

then proceed to remove the class to get the div visible:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#piclinks div a').click(function() {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#mainpic').hide();
        $('#altpic img').attr({'align':"middle",'src':link});
        $('#altpic').removeClass('is-hidden')
    return false;
    }); 
});
```

in CSS add:

```
.is-hidden {display:none;}
```

and remove display:none; for #altpic

Comment: Thx. I've tried your script without joy. It's not the img src or href or default behaviour part that's the prob. It's the div display that's not behaving.

Comment: you mean #altpic is not showing? In this case can you provide how it's hidden in the first place? Using CSS or JQuery?

Comment: CSS. #altpic isn't showing. And #mainpic isn't hidden. If I change the selector to #mainpic img, then img is hidden but that's not enough.

Comment: I made some change on my answer. Hope it'll help this time. :(

Comment: My problem is very peculiar. The jQuery is now at least adding the style "display:none" to #mainpic, and "display:block" to #altpic. All good. But for some unknown reason, the image in #mainpic is still rendered. Argghhhhh....

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
    $('#mainpic img').hide();
    $('#altpic img').show();
```

otherwise you are hiding/showing the div

Comment: Thank you. If the containing div i.e #mainpic is still rendered, and has a solid background, won't one just see the solid rendered background ?

Comment: @Tom yes that should be the output

Comment: Ahh - in which case i must have incorrect markup for #altpic 

How do I ensure it isn't hidden by the visible background of #mainpic ?